# PHP MYSQL group database out put

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I was looking here in the older posts and didnt find an answer

i have a table call links on the link i have 2 column

i already tried to do group by but it dosent let me to make an HTML table for 
every GEO

```
 SELECT geo,link_url FROM links OREDER BY geo

 1 link_url
 2 GEO
```

on my managing panel i want to arrange it like that

```
geo name (for example US)
--- link 1
--- link 2
--- link 3

geo name 2 (for example Uk)
--- link 4
--- link 5
--- link 6
```

should i do a a SELECT QUERY for every Geo ?
group by inside the query will help?

Comment: need to see data, query, and the output code

Answer (score 0):

Order By will sort, aren't you looking for:

```
SELECT geo,link_url FROM links GROUP BY geo
```

which will provide your unique geo.  Then, yes - you would then need to:

```
SELECT link FROM links where geo = 'insert geo value here' ORDER BY link
```

If you are using PHP, it would be something like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT geo,link_url FROM links GROUP BY geo";
$result = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $geo = $data['geo'];
   $strSQL2 = "SELECT link FROM links where geo = '" . $geo . "' ORDER BY link"
   $result2 = mysql_query($strSQL2);
   while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $geolink[$geo]['link'] = $data['link'];
   }
}
```

That should leave you an array with the structure which I believe is what you're looking for.

Comment: not working  :/ 
'
     $sql = "SELECT geo FROM link WHERE id = '4'";
     $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     while($row = $sql_query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["geo"];
     $sql2 = "SELECT link FROM links WHERE id = '4' AND geo     ='$row["geo"]'";
     $sql_query2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
     while($row2 = $sql_query2->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row2["link"];

         }

      }'

Comment: are you getting an error (or results from your echo statements)?  Also, can you put your code into the appropriate code type so it displays properly formatted.

Comment: <code>$sql = "SELECT geo FROM link WHERE id = '4'"; $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); while($row = $sql_query->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row["geo"]; $sql2 = "SELECT link FROM links WHERE id = '4' AND geo ='$row["geo"]'"; $sql_query2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2); while($row2 = $sql_query2->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row2["link"]; } } </code>

Comment: There's a invalid use of group by in the query

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample (database and code) and executed it to assure the answer is functional.

The database is named test.
The OpenDB.php is my way of openinng the database.  It returns $db as the connection string.

```
    <?php
include('OpenDB.php');
$strSQL = "SELECT geo,link_url FROM test.links GROUP BY geo";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
if(!$result) { exit ("Unable to connect to database"); }
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $geo = $data['geo'];
   $strSQL2 = "SELECT link_url FROM test.links where geo = '" . $geo . "' ORDER BY link_url";
echo "SQL2:" . $strSQL2 . "<br />";
   $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL2);
   if(!$result2) { exit("Unable to connect to database"); }
   while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
         $geolink[$geo][] = $data['link_url'];
   }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($geolink);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This resulted in the following result:
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => link1
        )

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => link2
        [1] => link2
        [2] => link2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => link3-1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => link3-2
    )
```

)